# Visual Studio 2017 debug error: "Frame not in module"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

After updating Visual Studio, I attempted to resume debugging, and got the following errors:

"Frame not in module"
"Exception thrown at 0x246E8BF8 in w3wp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000."

What do these mean and how do I resume debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[After doing some digging](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/debugger-doesnsharp39t-work-quotframe-not-in-modulequot), I got debugging working again by checking the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" box in Exception Settings (there's a link to Exception Setting in the popup that had the second error), then changing the "Solution Platforms" from "Mixed Platforms" to "Any CPU".

Comment: Did not help me. I have it on Any CPU with-/out exceptions runtime language ex ckeck... It works on VS2017 but not VS2019 pfffff....

Comment: How to change solution platform?

Answer (score 2):

This was problem for me when I was debuging CUDA program, and I was running Release (Cuda is slow in debug and has its own button to debug) on VS. So for anyone reading this, check it as well.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer Once you have enough reputation, you can use the comments section for further discussion

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the `.vs` and `obj` folders, closing and reopening did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

Future travellers to this page, beware: I had the "Frame not in module", and it seemed my Stored Procedure was not configured properly. It was missing an ELSE statement in between a couple of IF BEGIN END blocks. The SP compiled, saved and ran without warnings or errors in SQL Server, but just exited after the line where it had expected the ELSE statement.

After putting the ELSE statement in, all problems disappeared, including the "Frame not in module" error.

Answer (score 0):

Removing targetFramework=4.x from my compilation node in the web.config fixed this for me.