# Exception Thrown : w3wp.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-express, iis-express-10

I have an ASP.NET application which is hosted in IIS and for debugging, we Attach To Process and debug. Since yesterday, I am getting an error as

w3wp.exe has triggered a breakpoint.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCQzH.png)

Also, we see the error "Frame not in module"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3D1P.png)

Is it because our application is throwing an error?
Per our investigation No. Also, we tried creating a Sample ASP.NET application and the error is still the same error.

Has there been any windows update?
We do not have complete access to security and updates but after a quick check using powershell we did not find anything recently updated.

What we have tried?

- We have looked into a similar issue [Frame not in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47933932/visual-studio-2017-debug-error-frame-not-in-module) and tried the solution of checking the "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" box in Exception Settings but that did not help!
- We have tried resetting visual studio setting. Tools - Import and Export Settings - reset all setting
- We have tried enabling/disabling Just my code  (Tools -  options - Debugging)
- We have tried enabling/disabling Use manage compatibility mode  (Tools -  options - Debugging)
- Installed visual studio 2022 but that also does not work and throw error like "Unable to attach to the process. Operation not supported"
  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnW9m.png)

Comment: It’s just the typical IIS crash causing by something else. Experienced developers can read the disassembled instructions and see what’s up, but you might not be familiar with that. Install Debug Diagnostic Tool from Microsoft and use crash rules if you like. That tool can capture/analyze typical dumps for you

Comment: About how to fix Frame not in module, helpful support cases are really rare. May you can try [this](https://forum.juce.com/t/solved-visual-studio-2019-frame-not-in-module-debug-error/42564). Since create new test project and reset VS settings the same problem still occurs. Probably something in your development environment is causing this error. Analyzing the dump file using the analysis tools mentioned by the community member is the best advice.